# Send param with POST to Botframework (and different channel)

Tags: botframework

I'm working on bot project, the bot are going to work on different channel (web/messenger and probably other)

I'm actually at the proactive message, we want to send dynamic message to user, for example "You don't talk me from XXX time"

So I've made a new route in bot, for sending message with conversation references, it's work good on emulator/messenger for the moment, but we trying to add parameter to this request but we don't found any way to get param in bot.

```
server.post('/api/notify/:conversationID', async (req, res) => {

console.log(req)

if (req.params.conversationID){
    console.log(req.params.conversationID)
}


for (let conversationReference of Object.values(conversationReferences)) {

   if (typeof conversationReferences[req.params.conversationID] !== "undefined"){
        await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReferences[req.params.conversationID], async turnContext => {
            await turnContext.sendActivity(req.params.message);


        });
   }else {
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
        await turnContext.sendActivity(req.params.message);
    });
   }



}

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.writeHead(200);
res.write('<html><body><h1>Test send.</h1></body></html>');
res.end();
});
```

I also tried with GET, and sending parameter in URL like /api/notify/CONVID/MESSAGEtoUSER
But if the message length are more than 70 character, the bot return automatically method don't exist, it's like when the length are 'big' so but understand it like route and not like parameter...

Anyone have idea how can we get the param?

Thank!

EDIT :

Finally I found a way to pass param as POST call.

You need to enable bodyParser of restify, add this line :

```
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser())
```

in index.js

You can now get the body of POST route call ! 
:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by passing any params in an empty activity via the `channelData` property. Because the activity includes an empty string in the `text` property, the activity will not display when passed to the bot.

In this example, the proactive message is initiated from the browser.

```js
server.get('/api/notify/:userId', async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  for (const conversationReference of Object.values(conversationReferences)) {
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
      var reply = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };
      reply.channelData = { userId };
      reply.text = '';

      await turnContext.sendActivity(reply);
    });
  }

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.write('<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>');
  res.end();
});
```

**Proactive message sending the `userId` via `channelData`**

[image]

**`userId` is received by the bot via `activity.channelData`**

[image]

**Testing Web Chat also shows `userId` in the `activity.channelData`**

[image]

Hope of help!

Comment: Hi, thank for you reply ! :-)
In this way, I'm facing other problems.
I'm trying to send the content of message in param to. But if the lengtht of param are to expansive, api return me "RessourceNotFound" and use the param like route
Exemple : I call /api/notify/userId/Blablablablablabla... ( more than 50/70 character), it return me "/api/notify/userId/Blablablablablabla does not exist"
There is a limit for size or parameters? This why I've trying to achieves with post param aha

Comment: To avoid this, pass in a JSON object with the data and extract that on the server side. Passing a long message in the URL is not considered best practice.